# Странно работающий QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlayout

Я пишу проект на PyQt5, он состоит из нескольких окон. Сам проект уже на финальной стадии, поэтому я начал добавлять лейауты для окон. Со всеми окнами всё прошло отлично, кроме одного. Я всё ещё новичок в Qt, поэтому, потратив день на поиски решения, я сдался и пришёл сюда.

Я хочу, чтобы окно масштабировалось и выглядело так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке масштабировать окно получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то, при попытке растянуть окно растёт только `QLineEdit` и только в длину. Что я делаю не так?

Вот код:

```
class Ui_Append(object):
    def setupUi(self, AppendWindow):
        AppendWindow.resize(500, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AppendWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.time = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.time.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 85, 170, 40))
        self.time.setObjectName("timeEditWidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.time.setFont(font)
        self.time.setMinimumWidth(170)

        self.lable_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lable_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 170, 40))
        self.lable_1.setObjectName("lable_1Widget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lable_1.setFont(font)
        self.lable_1.setText('Выберите время')
        self.lable_1.setMinimumWidth(170)

        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 85, 170, 40))
        self.line.setObjectName("lineEditWidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.line.setFont(font)
        self.line.setMinimumWidth(170)

        self.lable_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lable_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 40, 170, 40))
        self.lable_2.setObjectName("lable_2Widget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lable_2.setFont(font)
        self.lable_2.setText('Введите значение')
        self.lable_2.setMinimumWidth(170)

        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 160, 180, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.push.setFont(font)
        self.push.setText('Подтвердить')
        self.push.setMinimumWidth(180)

        AppendWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class AppendWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Append):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AppendWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Новая запись')

        self.push.clicked.connect(self.get_value)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.grid.setHorizontalSpacing(20)
        self.grid.setVerticalSpacing(20)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(0, 0)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        self.grid.addWidget(self.lable_1, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lable_2, 0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.time, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.line, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.push, 2, 0, 2, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def get_value(self):
        value = self.line.text()
        time = self.time.text()
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect('notes.sqlite')
            cur = con.cursor()
            name = self.parent.comboBox.currentText()
            data = self.parent.label_2.text()
            data = data[-10:]
            id = cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ?""", (name,)).fetchall()
            t = cur.execute("""SELECT time FROM note WHERE user = ? AND data = ? AND time = ?""", (id[0][0], data, time)).fetchall()
            if len(t) > 0:
                raise NewException
            if ',' in value and value.count(',') == 1:
                m = value.find(',')
                value = value[:m] + '.' + value[m + 1:]
            value = float(value)
            if value <= 0 or value > 55.5:
                raise Exception
            value = str(value)
            self.parent.save(time, value)
            self.close()
        except NewException:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msgBox.addButton('ок', QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
            msgBox.setText("Запись на это время уже существует. Пожалуйста измените время"
                           "или очистите день и внесите данные снова")
            msgBox.exec_()
        except Exception:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msgBox.addButton('ок', QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
            msgBox.setText("Вы некорректно ввели значение. "
                           "Значение должно быть десятичным числом меньшим 55.5 "
                           "и большим 0.0 (Так как значений меньше 0.0 и больше "
                           "55.5 у живого человека быть не может.). Введите другое значение.")
            msgBox.exec_()
```

Comment: Для AppendWindow родителем(parent) является другое окно - основное окно проекта. Это нужно для передачи значений из AppendWindow в основное окно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QGridLayout::setRowStretch(int row, int stretch)
>
> Устанавливает коэффициент растяжения `stretch` строки `row`.
> Первая строка - это номер 0.
> Коэффициент растяжения относится к другим строкам в этой сетке.
> Ряды с более высоким коэффициентом растяжения занимают больше доступного места.
>
> Коэффициент растяжения по умолчанию равен 0.
> Если коэффициент растяжения равен 0 и никакая другая строка в этой таблице не может расти вообще,
> строка все равно может расти.

> void QGridLayout::setColumnStretch(int column, int stretch)
>
> Устанавливает коэффициент растяжения `stretch` для столбца `column`. Первый столбец - номер 0.
>
> Коэффициент растяжения относится к другим столбцам в этой сетке.
> Столбцы с более высоким коэффициентом растяжения занимают больше доступного пространства.
>
> Коэффициент растяжения по умолчанию равен 0.
> Если коэффициент растяжения равен 0 и ни один другой столбец в этой таблице не может
> увеличиваться вообще, столбец может увеличиваться.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Append(object):
    def setupUi(self, AppendWindow):
        AppendWindow.resize(500, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AppendWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.time = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.time.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 85, 170, 40))
        self.time.setObjectName("timeEditWidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.time.setFont(font)
        self.time.setMinimumWidth(170)

        self.lable_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lable_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 170, 40))
        self.lable_1.setObjectName("lable_1Widget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lable_1.setFont(font)
        self.lable_1.setText('Выберите время')
        self.lable_1.setMinimumWidth(170)

        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 85, 170, 40))
        self.line.setObjectName("lineEditWidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.line.setFont(font)
        self.line.setMinimumWidth(170)

        self.lable_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lable_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 40, 170, 40))
        self.lable_2.setObjectName("lable_2Widget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lable_2.setFont(font)
        self.lable_2.setText('Введите значение')
        self.lable_2.setMinimumWidth(170)

        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 160, 180, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.push.setFont(font)
        self.push.setText('Подтвердить')
        self.push.setMinimumWidth(180)

        AppendWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class AppendWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Append):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AppendWindow, self).__init__(parent)                          # ??? parent
        self.parent = parent

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Новая запись')

        self.push.clicked.connect(self.get_value)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.grid.setHorizontalSpacing(20)
        self.grid.setVerticalSpacing(20)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)                                        #  +++ 1
        self.grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(2, 1)                                        #  +++ 
        self.grid.setRowStretch(3, 1)                                        #  +++ 
        
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(0, 1)                                     #  +++ 
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(1, 1)                                     #  +++

        self.grid.addWidget(self.lable_1, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lable_2, 0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.time, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.line, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.push, 2, 0, 2, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def get_value(self):
        value = self.line.text()
        time = self.time.text()
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect('notes.sqlite')
            cur = con.cursor()
            name = self.parent.comboBox.currentText()
            data = self.parent.label_2.text()
            data = data[-10:]
            id = cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ?""", (name,)).fetchall()
            t = cur.execute("""SELECT time FROM note WHERE user = ? AND data = ? AND time = ?""", (id[0][0], data, time)).fetchall()
            if len(t) > 0:
                raise NewException
            if ',' in value and value.count(',') == 1:
                m = value.find(',')
                value = value[:m] + '.' + value[m + 1:]
            value = float(value)
            if value <= 0 or value > 55.5:
                raise Exception
            value = str(value)
            self.parent.save(time, value)
            self.close()
        except NewException:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msgBox.addButton('ок', QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
            msgBox.setText("Запись на это время уже существует. Пожалуйста измените время"
                           "или очистите день и внесите данные снова")
            msgBox.exec_()
        except Exception:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msgBox.addButton('ок', QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
            msgBox.setText("Вы некорректно ввели значение. "
                           "Значение должно быть десятичным числом меньшим 55.5 "
                           "и большим 0.0 (Так как значений меньше 0.0 и больше "
                           "55.5 у живого человека быть не может.). Введите другое значение.")
            msgBox.exec_()
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppendWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]